# how dose i add a permit to the auth url, antMatchers and securityMatchers dosnt work

Tags: spring-security

```
    @Bean
        public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                    .cors()
                    .and()
                    .csrf().disable()
                    //.authorizeHttpRequests((auth) -> auth
                    //      .requestMatchers("/auth/**")
                    //      .permitAll()
                    //      .anyRequest()
                    //      .authenticated())
                    //.httpBasic()
                    .authorizeHttpRequests()//insted of the commented code
                    .anyRequest()//insted of the commented code
                    .authenticated()//insted of the commented code
                    .and()
                    .sessionManagement()
                    .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                    .and()
                    .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider())
                    .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

            return http.build();
        }
```

this is the code, i cant add antMatcher/antMatchers cause it dosnt find it, and with the commented part and with a securetyMatcher, i only get an forbidden request on the /auth/login

im using spring boot 3.0.0

i tryed

```
http
                .cors()
                .and()
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeHttpRequests((auth) -> auth
                        .requestMatchers("/auth/login", "POST").permitAll()
                )
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider())
                .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
```

also with only

```
               .authorizeHttpRequests((auth) -> auth
                        .requestMatchers("/auth/login", "POST").permitAll()
                )
```

still forbidden

Comment: This might help you https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.8/migration/servlet/config.html#use-new-requestmatchers. In summary, Spring Security 6 removed `antMatchers` and others from the DSL. You can still use them via `.requestMatcher(AntPathRequestMatcher.antMatcher("/my-path"));`

Comment: @MarcusHertdaCoregio i´v red the side but i still cant get it to work(i also dont understand how the httpSecurety is logicly build, but i cant find a good side to explain)
i added my try to the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it worked with

```
@Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.cors(cors -> cors.disable());

        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> {
                    auth.anyRequest().authenticated();
                })
                .httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults());

        http
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
        return http.build();
    }
```

for me

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

As it is, your endpoint is necessarily protected.

Try like this

```java
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .cors().and().csrf().disable()
        .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
            .requestMatchers("/auth/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
        )
        .and()       
        .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
        .and()
        .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider())
        .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

        return http.build();
}
```

With this configuration, you authorize any user for "/auth/*" endpoints and protect all others.